# EF 4.4 -> 5 "Multiple versions were encountered" in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a solution with lots of class library projects and a MVC 4 website using them. I tried to upgrade .NET Framework from 4 to 4.5 and upgrade those class library projects, that each are using EF 4.4 models, to EF 5. But I'm getting "Multiple versions were encountered".

Here's what I done so far:

1. Changed target framework to 4.5 on all projects in solution
2. Updated reference to EF 5 on all projects using Nuget package manager
3. Changed my Web.Config in MVC project "section name="entityFramework... 5.0.0.0.."
4. Checked if multiple .edmx files were generated, but there wasnt.
5. "Cleaned build" + Restart didnt help
6. Searched whole solution for 4.4.0.0 but all were 5.0.0.0
7. ProviderManifestToken="2008" on all, same as before I started

What might be wrong here? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: You can try a search for some wrong key inside the .proj files of the libraries. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res://*/
```

In WebConfig doesn't work in EF5